# How to include parameters and link to results in SEDE query?

Tags: support, data-explorer, export

I think there should be a further option at [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) while executing a query. For instance, I want to send [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/949/what-is-my-accepted-answer-percentage-rate) (with the results). However, when I send the link to anyone the recipient has to enter the input and click query (+ input reCAPTCHA in some cases), which is not flexible.

For example, we want to include some query (with its results) on some of our public profile pages. However, when visitor goes to query, he can't see any results (as he "has" to run query again).

So, it's good if there was a parameter, added in the link, like:

https://data.stackexchange.com/............&execute=true

Going to that link should auto-execute the query and show results to the visitor. I think it will facilitate sharing with others.

At the least, if there was even static "Save results" (like Pastebin or Gist) to send directly to others, this might help in some cases.

Comment: Because these features (mostly) exist already, I've retagged this as [support] instead of a [feature-request].

Comment: @glorfindel thnks i didnt know that

Answer (score 20):

> So, it's good if there was a parameter, added in the link

It already exists, you can just add parameters like this:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/949/?UserId=2377343

This will directly execute the query for your user ID.

---

If you are *writing* a query, there even is a 'permalink' option which will generate the URL for you (see the status bar below for the generated link):

[image]

---

By appending `#results` to the URL, you can directly link to the results:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/949/?UserId=2377343#results

> At the list, if there was even static "save results" (like pastebin or gist) to send directly to others, this might help in some cases.

You can always choose to download the results as a CSV file.

Comment: Your user ID can be found in the URL of your profile page, after `/users/`. Mine is 4751173, yours is 2377343. You can't execute this particular query without a user ID; it might work for other queries.

Comment: now  I understand. you could add that sentence in your answer (that UserId is a MUST-HAVE parameter for execution)

Comment: *All* parameters in SEDE are must-haves (but it's possible to add default values).

Comment: What other parameters are there?  For example I believe `#Chart` runs the query and goes to the Chart tab?  Is it possible to get to other tabs or do anything else with the query string?

Comment: @ashleedawg I don't know exactly, but that's "just" an HTML anchor which works for *every* element on that page with an `id` attribute. If you inspect the source code you'll discover a lot more.